# TypeError: Cannot destructure property `compile` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, vuejs2

Steps to reproduce: I run `vue init webpack myapp` with options selected as per screenshot.

[image]

Then I got ouput as follows:

[image]

`npm run dev` works fine when I don't do `npm audit fix --force` or `npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server@3.1.10` and `npm install --save-dev url-loader@1.1.2` which I get with `npm audit`

[image]

When I got fixed and run `npm run dev`, not it's giving errors

[image]

Then I run `npm i -D webpack-cli` as recommended in the output.

But now I have the following error when running `npm run dev`

[image]

*Can't figure how to fix this issue...*

Comment: `npm audit fix` updates dangerous modules to the versions where vulnerability was fixed. In some cases it leads to incompatibility with other modules.

Comment: @alexmac in my case `npm audit fix` didn't work. I had to run `npm audit fix --force`, which in its turn, as I mentioned above `npm run dev` stopped working...

Comment: `force` flag means that `audit fix` installs semver-major updates to toplevel dependencies, not just semver-compatible ones. Looks like one of your dependencies requires the version that can't be updated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue is with the webpack-dev-server which shouldn't be used in production, so it's generally safe to have a vulnerability in this (until dependent packages update to support version 3.1)

```
npm install -D webpack-dev-server@3.0.0
```

Comment: Have fixed issue "Cannot destructure property 'compile' of 'compiler.hooks" while was starting `react-window` lib sources